# jsonp with wcf works with vs.net server but NOT on IIS

Tags: wcf, iis, jsonp

This is driving me nuts.  I have a .net 4, wcf service that is outputting jsonp.  It works using the built in web server with vs.net however if i try to host in iis7 on windows 7 64bit i don't get any response.

If I try to navigate to svc file while hosted in iis7 I get

"Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service."

If trying to access via client jquery jsonp request i don't get any response from the service being hosted in iis7

So, the configuration of the service (web.config) is fine when hosted within vs.net web server (just doesn't work with iis)

Here is the config

```
   <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
        <webHttp />
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <webHttpBinding>
      <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
    </webHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="ServiceSite.CustomersService">
      <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="ServiceSite.CustomersService"
                behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>

<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

The site must be ntlm/windows secured.
I added the following to the web.config bindings section

```
            <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        </security>
```

When browsing the svc file I now get Cross domain javascript callback is not supported in authenticated services
Really? Is this true jsonp is not supported?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably symptomatic of misconfiguration of the web site. Go to Authntication feature of the website on the IIS Manager and make sure it is setup.

[image: Sample]

Comment: The site has to have anonymous authentication disabled (it must be ntlm secured).  Sorry that I did not document that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure because of how JSONP cross domain works with today's shortcomings that you always have to implement your own custom security system.

I use SSL and HMAC security for JSONP cross domain authentication. I do the authentication myself on the service.

When doing JSONP you cannot set headers, or anything, on the request because it's done through adding  tags, not an actual XMLHTTP request object.